# Foreign key issue MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, csv, jdbc

I am having an issue with inputting data from a csv file into a mysql database using JDBC. I have already inserted a table called 'Poet' with the 'PoetName' being the priamry key.

I have populated that table with records that i have held in a CSV file, I then created another table called 'Poem' and it contains a foreign key which is 'PoetName' which references the poet table however whenever I try to populate the table with the CSV file for poems that contains matching values I am being displayed with the following error-

"Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

This is strange because the values I have for the primary key 'PoetName' are the same for the values I have used for the foreign key.

Does anyone have an idea of what the issue may be?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe there are extra spaces in the poet name. It would probably be better to use a numeric ID field as the foreign key.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: check for any character encoding issues. see which one failed and compare from both the sources

Answer (score 0):

If you're running into this error, one quick workaround is to add this line to your script:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

Another note is generally you want your primary key to be of type INT.